# JUnit 5 Exception Testing Equivalent of Junit 4

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have the following JUnit 4 test for exception:

```
@Test(expected = NotFoundException.class)
public void getRecipeByIdTestNotFound() throws Exception {

    Optional<Recipe> recipeOptional = Optional.empty();

    when(recipeRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(recipeOptional);

    Recipe recipeReturned = recipeService.findById(1L);

    //should go boom
}
```

I want help on the most efficient approach to test the same in JUnit 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage 1:

```
try{
    Optional<Recipe> recipeOptional = Optional.empty(); 
    when(recipeRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(recipeOptional); 
    Recipe recipeReturned = recipeService.findById(1L);
}catch(Exception e){
    AssertThat(e, instanceOf(NotFoundException.class));
}
```

Usage 2:

```
Assertions.assertThrow(NotFoundException.class, () -> {
    Optional<Recipe> recipeOptional = Optional.empty();
    when(recipeRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(recipeOptional);
    Recipe recipeReturned = recipeService.findById(1L);
});
```